# Optimize copy columns

Tags: excel, vba

I create a code for copy columns between sheets, but I want optimize the code for avoid repeat. What is the best way for optimize the code and avoid the repeations? A for loop?

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()

With Worksheets("CES")
    Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng3 = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng4 = .Range(.Cells(2, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng5 = .Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng6 = .Range(.Cells(2, "G"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng7 = .Range(.Cells(2, "H"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng8 = .Range(.Cells(2, "I"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng9 = .Range(.Cells(2, "J"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng10 = .Range(.Cells(2, "K"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng11 = .Range(.Cells(2, "N"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng12 = .Range(.Cells(2, "O"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp))
    Set SrcRng13 = .Range(.Cells(2, "P"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
End With
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("C3").Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("D3").Resize(SrcRng1.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng1.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("E3").Resize(SrcRng2.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng2.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("F3").Resize(SrcRng3.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng3.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("G3").Resize(SrcRng4.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng4.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("K3").Resize(SrcRng5.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng5.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("L3").Resize(SrcRng6.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng6.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("M3").Resize(SrcRng7.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng7.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("N3").Resize(SrcRng8.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng8.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("O3").Resize(SrcRng9.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng9.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("P3").Resize(SrcRng10.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng10.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("Q3").Resize(SrcRng11.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng11.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("R3").Resize(SrcRng12.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng12.Value
Worksheets("RESUL").Range("S3").Resize(SrcRng13.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng13.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it on purpose that you only copy columns A - K and then N-P or did you just miss L and M ?

Comment: Only copy A-k and n-p

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Sorry I want only copy the columns from A to K and then from N to P. I don't want the L and M column.

Comment: And then you want to distribute them fro C-H, K-S, right?

Comment: Yes friend it's right

Comment: Do the source column have different sizes = different number of values/rows? Or are they always of the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP's comments you could just copy the values of the columns in question

```
Sub copyColumns()

    Dim srcWks As Worksheet
    Dim trgWks As Worksheet        
    
    Set srcWks = Worksheets("CES")
    Set trgWks = Worksheets("RESUL")
    
    cp srcWks, trgWks, "A:E", "C:G"
    cp srcWks, trgWks, "F:K", "K:P"
    cp srcWks, trgWks, "N:P", "Q:S"
    
End Sub


Function cp(srcWks As Worksheet, trgWks As Worksheet, col1 As String, col2 As String)
    Dim srcRg As Range
    Dim trgRg As Range
    
    Set srcRg = srcWks.Columns(col1)
    Set srcRg = srcRg.Resize(srcRg.Rows.CountLarge - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Set srcRg = usedRg(srcRg)
    
    Set trgRg = trgWks.Columns(col2)
    Set trgRg = trgRg.Resize(trgRg.Rows.CountLarge - 1).Offset(1)
    Set trgRg = trgRg.Resize(srcRg.Rows.CountLarge, srcRg.Columns.CountLarge)
    trgRg.Value = srcRg.Value

End Function

Function usedRg(rg As Range) As Range
    
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
   
    lastRow = rg.Cells.Find(What:="*" _
        , Lookat:=xlPart _
        , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , searchOrder:=xlByRows _
        , searchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   

    lastColumn = rg.Cells.Find(What:="*" _
        , Lookat:=xlPart _
        , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , searchOrder:=xlByColumns _
        , searchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = rg.Parent
    With wks
        Set usedRg = Intersect(rg, .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)))
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: But I want begin copy in the row 2 (worksheet=CES) and paste in the row 3 (worksheet=Resul)

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry, I overlooked this. But target starts at row 1, right?

Comment: Target starts at row 2

Comment: Ok, I changed the code

Comment: the code copy in the second row of RESUL I want copy in the third row

Comment: sorry for my english friend. The code copy correct but paste in the second row of RESUL, I want paste in the third row

Comment: @jSbeginner Replace this line: `Set trgRg = trgRg.Resize(trgRg.Rows.CountLarge - 1).Offset(1)` with this: `Set trgRg = trgRg.Resize(trgRg.Rows.CountLarge - 2).Offset(2)`